# Open ID Connect Provider - Persist ID Tokens?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm writing an Open ID Connect Provider in Rails, basically refactoring this example [Here](https://github.com/nov/openid_connect_sample).

My question is - do ID Tokens need to be persisted on the server at all? If I'm just signing the ID Token and sending it to the RP, can't I just generate the ID Token when the RP asks for it (such as with an idtoken response type in the request) and not worry about saving it in a database on my end? Basically use a plain old ruby object for the IDToken rather than an ActiveModel object.

It seems to me that once the RP receives an ID Token, they use it to get information about the Resource Owner and won't send it back to the provider like an access token. Or am I missing something here and I SHOULD be saving the ID Tokens in the provider's db?

I know Nat Sakimura explains [here](http://nat.sakimura.org/2013/07/28/write-openid-connect-server-in-three-simple-steps/) that in the `code` flow of OAuth / OIDC, you should save the ID Token when passing the authorization code back to the RP but I feel like I could just generate the Token when they send the code back and ask for the access token (along with the id token).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you don't need to generate and store the `id_token` right away but in a lot of cases the OP needs to retain information about the request - e.g. the requested scopes and the requested claims - in order to generate the required `id_token` so it may make sense to generate the token right away and store it as a self-contained unit.

Note that you'll also need to retain the `client_id` and the `redirect_uri` to be able to check it when the `code` is exchanged, and optionally the `nonce`.

But indeed there's no inherent need to generate the `id_token` right away as you suggest.